# In iphone what is the name for the red circle with number of unread messages in it

Tags: iphone, naming-conventions

Is it a "tooltip" or  "bubble" or something else ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for a quick and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called an application icon badge. It can be modified by setting the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property on the shared `UIApplication` instance .

You can set it like so

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:99];
```

Doing that puts the number 99 onto the application badge. Setting it to zero hides the badge .The default value for this property is zero.

Source : UIApplication Reference

Comment: can something else be put in there? or is it always a number?

Comment: The property is an NSInteger so i guess it can only be a number.

Answer (score 1):

It is set via `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property in `UIApplication`, it should probably be "Badge" or "Badge number"

Answer (score 1):

You also have badge numbers on [UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
int tabBarWithBadge = 2 ; //set which tab you want the red badge currently its 2
int badgeValue = 007;

 [[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]  tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabBarWithBadge] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeValue];
```

Here tabBarController is the UItabBarController which is set in the appDelegate file